# How to use postfix to send emails

Tags: linux, postfix, sendmail

I am trying to use postfix to send emails from linux host to my email address which is hosted on Microsoft Exchange Server. Linux host is on the same network. I do not understand all the detailed instructions. I want is to use a simple command line to send email from linux host to my email address.

Something like:

```
sendmail abc@company.com < mail.file
```

How can I do that ?

Comment: What's wrong with the command above? It works!

Comment: Thanks. I had to add myhostname = localhost in /etc/postfix/main.cf. It works now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Postfix is a full blown SMTP suite, you don't need that to send simple emails.

For that, there's many command line tools: `mailx` (aka `mail`) `pine`, `mutt`.

I'm a mailx fan myself:

`mail -s 'subject' user@email.com < file`

Mutt is more comprehensive and allows attachments.

Comment: Thanks for response. I tried using mail the way you have demoed. But I don't see any emails coming to me. Is there some configuration I need to change.

Comment: Make sure you give things some time - Also check your spam folder.

Comment: There are other things that may be holding the email from delivery - look at `tail /var/log/maillog` to see if there's any clues (Assuming your mail log file may differ slightly in name)

Comment: Thanks. I had to add myhostname = localhost
in /etc/postfix/main.cf

Comment: Its working now.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [SendEmail](http://caspian.dotconf.net/menu/Software/SendEmail/#download) as well

Comment: Can you give me the commandline options to do that ? I tried that also but it does not seem to be working.